# Create Task Activity not working within a journey

Tags: marketing-cloud

I've created a journey with a data extension as its entry source. I'm creating Task Activities which look like this:
Task > Create New > Assigned to ID, Subject, Status, Priority, and RelatedtoID (using SalesforceID)

I activate the journey and look to Sales Cloud, but there are no new tasks created. The journey is set up as a test for this one task.

I know the connection does work, because I can create leads with object activity.

Am I missing something? I've tried re-creating it a few times and I can't get tasks to be created.

Answer (score 0):

At the root, it did not create the object because SFDC did not accept it. I’ve found that its typically not created due to SFDC validation rules. I would check field lengths, data types, if there are any pick list fields - your data will need to conform to one of those exact values.

Comment: Or missing a required field

Comment: I was able to find that the "Related To" field was the culprit. I'm trying to relate the task to a lead or contact based on the SalesforceID but I can't find one that pushes data into the task. I'm currently trying the NameID and not having luck using the ID from entry source or contact data.